# Get all matches from text with regex

Tags: python, regex

I Have text

Text example (only example, I can't show real text):

`some words getServerResponse={go [for {a walk}] goodby }something hello world text={what[ i want {in curl} ]braces}, another string text={second[ {text what} i ]want number two}`

In this example "text" - it is tag which I need to get. We can see that all information I need is contained in curl braces after "text=".

I try to use this template:
`text=(.*)`
and expect to get from my text two elements in list:

```
{what[ i want {in curl} ]braces}, another string text={second[ {text what} i ]want number two}
{second[ {text what} i ]want number two}
```

Doesn't matter that first element contains second part, because from first element I get only what  is between the first open curl brace and curl brace that closes the first one:

`what[ i want {in curl} ]braces`

But this `text=(.*)` template gives me only one variant

`{what[ i want {in curl} ]braces}, another string text={second[ {text what} i ]want number two}`

How can I get all matches from my text as list elements?

Comment: The language in your question here is somewhat confusing and feels like you could have put some more effort into learning some regex before asking the question here.  Anyway, could you please elaborate on what is the exact output you are looking for?

Comment: @PubuduSitinamaluwa expected result in code snippet.
I want to get two elements in final list for each "text="

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that all braces will be in the given format, I came up with this regex.

```
(text=)(\{(\w|\[|\s|\{|\}|\])+)
```

This will capture the nested element after each `text=`. Note that I have added 3 matching groups. 3rd group can be ignored for now.

`Group1` => `text=`

`Group2` => `{what[ i want {in curl} ]braces}` and `{second[ {text what} i ]want number two}`

You can use match all and extract the second capturing group to get your desired result.

[RegexDemo](https://regex101.com/r/2PTBtX/1)